# What determines the maximum size of array?

Tags: arrays, memory, malloc, ram, processor

I know there is an upper limit on array size. I want to understand what determines the maximum size of an array? Can someone give a simple detailed explanation?

Answer (score 0):

It depends, on the language, library, operating system.

For an in-memory array which is what most languages offer by default, the upper limit is the address space given to the process.  For Windows this is 2 or 3 GB for 32-bit applications, and for 64-bit applications it is the smaller of 8 TB and (physical RAM + page file size limit).

For a custom library using disk space to (very slowly) access an array, the limit will probably be the size of the largest storage volume.  With RAID and 10+ TB drives that could be a very large number.

Once you know the memory limit for an array, the upper limit on the number of elements is (memory / element size).  The actual limit will often be less if the element is small, since the array addressing might use 32-bit unsigned integers which can only address 4 GB elements.

This is for simple contiguous, typed arrays offered by languages like C++.  Languages like PHP where you can define `a['hello'] = 'bobcat'; a[12] = 3.14;` are more like maps and can use much more memory per element since they store a value for the index

Comment: Even if there is an upper limit on ram size,  why is an array size less than the actual memory.

Comment: By "actual" memory to you mean the total memory of the PC, or the 2 - 3 GB process address space limits of 32-bit applications?  I listed one common reason (index data type of 32-bit integer) others are going to be specific to a language's implementation.  It would help if you go into more detail.